# Multiple Drupal website login

Tags: multi-sites

We have a number of Drupal websites to login to. Is there an automated solution to login to each one? They are not on the same domain, not on the same server for that matter.

Comment: Are you looking for a single sign-on solution, or just a way to log in to multiple sites in your browser using different usernames/passwords?

Comment: just a way to login into multiple websites ... so ideally a list of websites and a login button next to each one.

Comment: Why not use the browser's "remember login" feature?